# How to add Images of products being purchased to Order Review part in Magento?

Tags: magento

How do I add images of the products being purchased to Order Review section in the Magento checkout?

I want the product image to be seen in the Order Review?

Answer (score 8):

The design templates for the Order Review table are found in frontend/{your_theme}/decault/template/checkout/onepage/review/ folder. The files you would need to update are info.phtml (to add the column) and item.phtml (to add the actual image).

frontend/{your_theme}/decault/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml

```
  <table class="data-table" id="checkout-review-table">
    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): $colspan = $rowspan = 2; else: $colspan = $rowspan = 1; endif; ?>
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" /> <!-- <---Add this new col in table description -->
    ...
```

Then find the table head and add your image column:

```
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan ?>">&nbsp;</th> <!-- Here's the empty col for the image -->
            <th rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
            <th colspan="<?php echo $colspan ?>" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
    ...
```

frontend/{your_theme}/decault/template/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml

Right at the beginning of the item.phtml file, add your image:

```
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php $_item = $this->getItem()?>
<tr>
    <!-- Product Image Here -->
    <td><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(75); ?>" width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></td>
    <td><h3 class="product-name"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?></h3>
...
```

REMEMBER - 
Don't change the core files, but update template files in your own theme.

Answer (score 2):

In addition you have to edit the totals template:

frontend/{your_theme}/decault/template/checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml

to adjust the botto column colspan:

```
<?php if ($this->getTotals()): ?>
<tfoot>
    <?php $_colspan = $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices() ? 6 : 4; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the empty column for `info.phtml` should use `$colspan` otherwise its width becomes too great:

```
<th rowspan="<?php echo $colspan ?>">&nbsp;</th>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml

Add the following code

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());

<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(75, 75); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product['name']); ?>" border="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the table in `info.phtml` to keep the tables consistent with the cart

```
<table class="data-table" id="checkout-review-table">
    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): $colspan = $rowspan = 2; else: $colspan = $rowspan = 1; endif; ?>
    <col width="1" /> <!-- <---Add width="1" to first column (Image) -->
    <col />           <!-- <---no width for 'Product Name' to show all options nicely -->
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" /> <!-- <---Add this new col in table description -->
```